# Matching PHP and Objective-C SHA password hash

Tags: php, objective-c, security, hash, passwords

I need to sync up PHP and Objective-C clients such that they can log in using the same credentials. I've found several different methods to hash passwords for each, but the problem is that none of their outputs match!

Does anyone have code for both PHP and Objective-C that will apply a SHA256 (or equivalent) hashing algorithm such that their output is identical?

Currently I'm using this for Objective-C:

```
//salt the password
NSString *saltedPassword = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"<passwd input>", kSalt];

//prepare the hashed storage
NSString* hashedPassword = nil;
unsigned char hashedPasswordData[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

//hash the pass
NSData *data = [saltedPassword dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
if (CC_SHA1([data bytes], [[NSNumber numberWithInt:[data length]] doubleValue], hashedPasswordData)) {
    hashedPassword = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:hashedPasswordData length:sizeof(hashedPasswordData) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}
```

And this for PHP:

```
$password = "<passwd input>" . "<salt>";

$password = sha1($password);
```

Also, this Github post seems it would be extremely helpful, but the objective-c portion doesn't work: https://gist.github.com/pcperini/2889493

Comment: I don't see `"<salt>"` anywhere in your objective C code

Comment: It's added as a compiler-level macro called kSalt - you can see it in the first line.

Comment: Do you realize that making your salt a compile-time constant is a terrible idea? It almost completely defeats the purpose of salting.

Comment: Andrew: I'm no longer tackling this problem in this way but for future reference, what's a better way of accomplishing this?